# Why there is no SelectToArray method in System.Linq.Enumerable

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, collections

So i'd like to ask: why we have only selector that returns an enumerable? For example, i have frequently situation, when i must modify each value of array, for example:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
a = a.Select(x=>x*2).ToArray();
```

so here we get an enumerable, and only after it we can convert it back into array.
We can try to use Array.ForEach, but only if we could modify the source. But if we have array of reference types and can't modify them, we should anyway write something like this

```
SomeClass[] a = FillSomeClassArray();
SomeClass[] b = a.Select(x=> ((SomeClass)x.Clone()).Modify()).ToArray();
```

in my case i'm using my own class

```
public static class CollectionHelper
{
    public static TResult[] SelectToArray<T, TResult>(this ICollection<T> source, Func<T, TResult> selector)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (selector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        var result = new TResult[source.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T t in source)
        {
            result[i] = selector(t);
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

here we haven't double-convertation, when we haven't predicate we know length of result and we should use this information. I know that MS shouldn't do all the work instead of me, but afaik it's functionaloty standard enough.

Comment: btw, there is ToList().ForEach()

Comment: I want to get an array from source, calling only one method. `ToList().ForEach` is not better, that simple `Select.ToArray()` and so on

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with adding `SelectToArray` to the framework is consistency. If you add `SelectToArray`, you should also add each of the following:

- `CastToArray<T>`
- `ConcatToArray<T>`
- `RepeatToArray<T>`
- `ReverseToArray<T>`
- `SkipToArray<T>`
- `OfTypeToArray<T>`
- `TakeToArray<T>`

While we're at the subject of adding new methods, what's wrong with adding the same optimization to lists? Now we also need

- `SelectToList<T>` (similar to the one that started it all)
- `CastToList<T>`
- `ConcatToList<T>`
- ... and so on - I'm sure you got the idea.

Considering the minuscule savings from knowing the size of the target array or the target list, such major refactoring is impractical. You would be able to achieve the same effect with a simple method like this:

```
static T[] CopyToArray(
    this IEnumerable<T> source
,   T[] result
,   int pos = 0
,   int? lengthOrNull = null
) {
    int length = lengthOrNull ?? result.Length;
    foreach (var item in source) {
        if (pos > length) break;
        result[pos++] = item;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now the caller can combine the existing LINQ functionality with this method to compose all of the above `XyzToArray` methods, like this:

```
IList<MyClass> data = ...
int[] res = data.Select(x => x.IntProperty).CopyToArray(new int[data.Count]);
```

You would also be able to write results of LINQ queries into different parts of an existing array, like this:

```
IList<MyClass> data1 = ...
IList<MyClass> data2 = ...
int[] res = new int[data1.Count+data2.Count];
data1.Select(x => x.IntProperty).CopyToArray(res, 0, data1.Count);
data2.Select(x => x.IntProperty).CopyToArray(res, data1.Count, data2.Count);
```

Comment: You think `data.Select(x => x.IntProperty).CopyToArray(new int[data.Count]);` is better, than `data.Select(x => x.IntProperty).ToArray()` ?

About the same method for list: we can write single method for list and after it just return inner list's array if we need an array.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky `CopyToArray(new int[data.Count])` is definitely faster, for the same reason as your `SelectToArray` is faster. The `XyzToList` methods could share a great deal of implementation, but you would need to add signatures for these methods to `Enumerable`, which would bloat an already large interface even more.